# If I assign a method to a variable is the method called in java?

Tags: java

these are my two classes

```
   public class Main {
         public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          Init init = new Init();
         final String init1 = init.init(); }}

public class Init {

protected String init() throws IOException {
     final String command = "ipconfig";
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime(); //executing commands on cmd
     Process process = rt.exec(command);
     InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    String val = "";

    if (s.hasNext()){
        val = s.next();
    } else {
        val = "";
    }

    return val;
```

would init1 being initialized cause my program to execute the command line command? or would i have to call init.init(); everytime i wanted the command to run?

Comment: Putting `}}` at the end of lines and haphazard indentation make your code harder to read. You are more likely to get people to read your code if it is readable.

Comment: Yes; calling a method causes the method to be called.  What don't you understand?

Comment: Java will only do something if you tell it to. So you need to call `init.init()` if you want `ipconfig` to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing a String in your variable inti1.
Therefore, if you "initialize" init1, you will get the String that your first call of init.init() returned. This is the only line where your init.init() call is done. If you reference init1 afterwards, no function gets called because the variable is just a String.

If you want to call a function in Java, you have to call the function. You can not store a function in a variable name and call the variable name as you could in JS.

Answer (score 3):

You're *not* assigning the method itself to a variable - you're calling the method, and then assigning the return value of the method to a variable.

With regards to

> or would i have to call init.init(); everytime i wanted the command to run?

As written, the method call will definitely be executed. If you wanted to run `init()` a second time, though, then yes, you'd have to call it again.

Comment: Maybe that was just the result of poor English skills

Comment: @JoakimDanielson The OP seems to have confusion about when this will be called.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes, it is called !
but if you have like too much code is better to put it in a method and add the return type you want, and then you can call it, it becomes more readable and short!

then you call that new method in your code, this way you will call your method for once!